# Different Censor Scripts in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out why one version of my code works, while the other doesn't.

The goal of the assignment is to create a function called `censor` that takes two strings, text and word, as input. It should return the text with the word you chose replaced with asterisks.

This is the first snippet of code that I wrote, and it didn't work.

```
def censor(text, word):

  import string 

  text = string.split(text)

  for index in range(0, len(text)):
     if word == text[index]:
        text[index] = len(word) * '*'

  text = string.join(text)
  return text
```

The above snippet returned an error:

```
Oops, try again. Your function fails on censor("hey hey hey","hey"). It returns "* * * h e y h e y" when it should return "*** *** ***".
```

The second snippet of code is below, and did work.

```
def censor(text, word):

    import string 

    text = string.split(text)

    for index in range(0, len(text)):
        if text[index] == word:
            text[index] = "*" * len(word)

    return " ".join(text)
```

I don't understand why `text = string.join(text)` doesn't work while `" ".join(text)` does.

Comment: What version of Python are you running? `string.join(list)` was deprecated in version 2.x, to be removed in 3.x.

Comment: 1) Don't assign the result of `split` (a list) back to `text`. Use a different variable name. 2) Don't iterate using an `index`. The Pythonic way is `for w in listOfWords:`. 3) Don't assign the result for `join` (a string) to `text`. Use a different variable name.

Comment: For Barmar, I'm using Codecademy on the web, so I'm not sure which version of Python they are using. It helps to know they deprecated string.join(list) and removed it later though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read up on `string.join`. You're supposed to call `join` on the string you want to join `text` with. For example,

```
>>> ', '.join(['a', 'b', 'c']
'a, b, c'
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense to me. I thought when I read the documentation on string.join, I needed to type out string.join, not the string I wanted to join. This helps a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You can do it more easily with regular expressions:

```
import re
def censor(text, word):
    return re.sub(r'\b' + word + r'\b', '*', text)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: why doesn't the first function work?